# How to see my QT UI when I'm developing a QT Dynamic Library with GUI?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to develop a QT cross-platform **dynamic library** (.dll and .so) that **contains QT UI inside of it** (window, buttons, labels, etc...). So, when the "main application" calls this library, a new QT window opens in the GUI.

To do this, I created a QT dynamic library project, I put my code and draw my UI in it.
**It compiles Ok!** And I got the output file: Windows (*.dll) and Linux (.so).

But when I click in the "Run" QT Creator button this project **cannot launch.** I understand this, because the output file of this project **is not a binary application....it is only a dynamic library.**

So I'm doing a "blind developing" process. **I can't see the UI final result** of my QT dynamic library.

**How can I setup the QT Creator to be able to test and see this UI running** in this special case?

Comment: How about creating a demo/example app that uses the library?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a single Qt project containing your main application and your library.

It would be handy to take a look at the Echo Plugin Example.